# Android display action bar items on real device

Tags: android, gradle, android-actionbar

In my project, action bar items are not displayed properly. On an emulator, they show without icons (only inside the 3 dots), i set `android:showAsAction="always"`. And on a real device they do not show at all.

This is my build gradle:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: 'Parse-*.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.+'
    compile 'com.pushbots:pushbots-lib:2.0.13@aar'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.8.0'
    compile files('libs/java-json.jar')
}
```

I set `minSdkVersion 15`.
Please advice me how can i fix it.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For your reference:
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html

Menu items displayed based on your Android version of emulator/device.